# Can't configure knockout validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to configure knockout validation, but my settings seem to be getting ignored.  This is how I'm trying to configure it

```
var knockoutValidationSettings = {
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorMessageClass: 'error',
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorsAsTitle: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    decorateElementOnModified: true,
    decorateInputElement: true
};
ko.validation.init(knockoutValidationSettings);

ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#dropzone')[0]);
```

I know the options object isn't the problem because this works perfectly

```
var knockoutValidationSettings = {
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorMessageClass: 'error',
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorsAsTitle: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    decorateElementOnModified: true,
    decorateInputElement: true
};
//ko.validation.init(knockoutValidationSettings);

ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(vm, $('#dropzone')[0], knockoutValidationSettings);
```

How can I get the init function to work?  Obviously I'd like to move this initialization to a single place at the root of my application.

Comment: You can try to pass `true` as the second argument to `init` : `ko.validation.init(knockoutValidationSettings, true);`

Comment: @nemesv - ah - that looks like was the solution.  Can you post as an answer - ideally with a blurb on what that true does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that the validation plugin has been already initialized by the time you call `ko.validation.init`.

So you need to pass in `true` as the second argument to force the initialization to use the new configuration:

```
ko.validation.init(knockoutValidationSettings, true);
```

What can initialize the validation plugin?

- any call to `ko.applyBindings` or `ko.applyBindingsWithValidation`
- any call to `ko.validation.init` or `ko.validation.configure`

The `ko.applyBindingsWithValidation` version works because it updates the configuration - under the covers - even if the plugin has been already initialized.

Comment: btw - I moved my init call to before all applyBindings and it works beautifully (without the true flag).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue due to an erroreous configuration. In order to mimic our current behaviour I had set the **errorMessageClass** property to "field-validation-valid ui top pointing red basic label".

It turned out that **removing the "field-validation-valid**" class (which is used by ASP.NET MVC ClientSide / jQuery validation) somehow solved my issues and the knockout validation worked as expected.